# Is usr/local/bin the correct directory to place JAR files?

Tags: terminal, applescript, homebrew, java

I have built an application that includes a JAR file I developed and I've had issues trying to run it correctly from the AppleScript application with:

```
set foobar to POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents/Resources/Scripts/foobar" as text
```

I have thought about checking `usr/local/bin` if the JAR file exists and then copying the JAR from the application to `usr/local/bin` but I'm unsure if this is the correct place to add JAR files so I can call them from AppleScript or through terminal. Is there a better approach to do this? I do have another block that checks to see if a program has been installed by Homebrew by checking `/usr/local/Cellar/` then running the rest of the AppleScript application with `do shell script` but I'm unsure where all installed additional programs should be placed so I can run them with AppleScript and Terminal. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Could you expand on what issues you've experienced when placing the JAR files in `Contents/Resources/Scripts/`?

Comment: @jaume it throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a [SIP perspective](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899), `/usr/local/bin` is perfectly fine to place JAR files.

SIP excludes the directories:

- `/usr/local`
- `/Libraries`
- `/Applications`

Anything in these directories can be read/written/executed.  Which one of those makes more sense for you to place your JAR files is entirely up to you.  (IMO), since it is a run-time and presumably it's part of an application, putting it in a sub-directory within the `/Applications` directory is not a bad place to start.

Comment: but will the `bin` also allow for me to able to execute the JAR with `foobar command` in the terminal if placed there?

Comment: SIP doesn't prevent execution.